Reporting results for time-invariant predictors in latent growth curve models
I am results for reporting a time invariant predictor of the intercept and slope factors within a latent growth model, adjusted for covariates such as age and sex. My dependent variables and covariates have not been standardised (i.e., they are the raw scores). However, my predictor variable was converted to a z-score (i.e., M = 0, SD =1) prior to entering in the the latent growth model.

Am I right in thinking that the use of "B" indicates unstandardized coefficients, whereas "β" or "b" indicates standardized coefficients?

If so, when reporting the results for the time invariant predictor of the intercept/slope factors in my model, should I use "B" (capitalized), "β" (beta) or "b" (lowercase)? Given that only the predictor is standardised.


Thanks.

There's very little consistency in the use of symbols - across and even within disciplines. In LISREL (the original structural equation modeling program) a lower case $\beta$ is an unstandardized parameter parameter that represents a regression coefficient between an endogenous latent variable to an exogenous latent variable, and upper case beta $B$ is the matrix of these coefficients. (The coefficients from endogenous to endogenous latents are $\gamma$ and the matrix is $\Gamma$.)
In some statistics packages B is the coefficient in regression, and beta is the standardized coefficient. And \$beta$ is also the probability of a type II error.
Much of the time, a Greek letter represents a population parameter, and non-Greek is sample statistic (e.g. $\sigma$ vs $s$ or $sd$) but that rule is broken in the previous paragraph.
Don't rely on conventions. Define your terms and explain what you mean.
